# Divisão por colunas na conversão para CSV

Tags: python, csv

Preciso fazer um CRUD pro registro de alunos, e logo depois, converter esses dados para uma planilha, e por enquanto, a parte de salvar para .csv está assim:

```
alunos_json = json.dumps(alunos, indent=True)

with open('abc.csv', 'w+') as file:
    file.write(alunos_json)
```

O problema é: quando eu abro o arquivo com os dados do programa, os alunos cadastrados ficam um abaixo do outro:

[image]

E eu queria que ficasse organizado mais ou menos dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

alunos_json = json.dumps(alunos, indent=True)
df = pd.DataFrame(alunos_json)
df.to_csv(r'alunos.csv')
```

Instale o pandas ou use o https://colab.research.google.com

Pode começar por aqui https://colab.research.google.com/drive/10Lm7b1UKK5Jq5oQgLUNUDOLWGTwz8DKl?usp=sharing